# How to update yum repository automatically

Tags: rhel, yum, software-updates

I have an RHEL 6.9 box serving as the `yum` repository for other machines in the network. Is there a proper way to update this repository with new packages when they are released by Red Hat?

This machine is registered with Red Hat and is able to pull RPM packages from Red Hat repositories. So, one way I can think of is to periodically download new packages available without installing them (*using the `--downloadonly` option*) to the repository directory and then run `createrepo --update` on the repository. This way the repository is kept updated with the new RPM packages from Red Hat. Though this will work just fine and serve my purpose, I would like to know whether there is a more proper or established method to keep the yum repository updated with the new packages from Red Hat.

Comment: RedHat would say: Satellite

Answer (score 2):

Check out `reposync` it is built for this:

> reposync is used to synchronize a remote yum repository to a local
>   directory, using yum to retrieve the packages.

Link **[here](https://linux.die.net/man/1/reposync)**.